# Keyboard click persists

Tags: 12.10, keyboard

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I find that button clicks for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> persist for a second or two. That is, if I press <kbd>A</kbd>, I get small `a`. However, if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, wait for a second and press <kbd>A</kbd>, I get a capitalized `A`. Note I am not pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> together to produce the uppercase letter, there's a gap of a second between two presses.

This is very annoying because whenever I am on a page in `Firefox` and accidentally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scroll down using touchpad it produces zoom out effect and font gets smaller.

Please suggest a remedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you enabled some of the "Universal Access" features. In `system settings` way down you find `Universal Access`. Select it and then click on the `typing` tab. Disable all settings in that tab.